# Why doesn't my PHP code check every row of the required MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

i need to loop through a table of myn, check one of its columns(**id**) during each row and match these **id** values in a another table to obtain the value known as **useragent** from it.

but currently theres something wrong with my while loop this only checks the **id** value of the first row only(it does not keep on checking every row)

```
$myarray = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_105");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myarray)){
    $table = 'table_105';
    $update = mysql_query("SELECT id as unp FROM $table");
    $col = mysql_fetch_assoc($update);
    $col_id = ($col["unp"]);

    $var1 = mysql_query("SELECT useragent as ua FROM paneltb WHERE id = $col_id");
    $col3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($var1);
    $col_ua = ($col3["ua"]);

    $browser = get_browser($col_ua, true);
    $platform = $browser['platform'];
    $device_name = $browser['device_name'];
    $browser_name = $browser['browser'];
    $version = $browser['version'];

    mysql_query("
            INSERT INTO table_tester(`trackerID`,`id`, `timestamp`, `useragent_browser`,`useragent_OS`,`useragent`)
            SELECT `trackerID`, `id`, `timestamp`, `useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`,'".$col3["ua"]."'
            FROM $table")
            or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: if you're expecting `$update = mysql_query("SELECT id as unp FROM $table");` to yield multiple rows, then you need to put the fetching inside another while loop also

Comment: actually what i need to do is get the "id" use it in another table to match it with the "id" in that particular table, and fetch the useragent corresponding to that id

Comment: Why not use `join`, let the database do the matching? Your last query `mysql_query` doesn't look like a valid `query` either.

Comment: cant make a join, useragent value had to be fetched from outside

Answer (score 0):

Its because your code is for only one row if you want to check all rows then put your content inside while loop for id and useragent like:

```
$myarray = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_105");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myarray)){
$table = 'tracktable_105';
$update = mysql_query("SELECT id as unp FROM $table");
while($col = mysql_fetch_assoc($update))
{
$col_id = ($col["unp"]);

$var1 = mysql_query("SELECT useragent as ua FROM paneltb WHERE id = $col_id");
while($col3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($var1))
{
$col_ua = $col3["ua"];

$browser = get_browser($col_ua, true);
$platform = $browser['platform'];
$device_name = $browser['device_name'];
$browser_name = $browser['browser'];
$version = $browser['version'];
mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO table_tester(`trackerID`,`id`,`timestamp`,`useragent_browser`,`useragent_OS`,`useragent`) SELECT `trackerID`, `id`, `timestamp`, `useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`,'".$col3["ua"]."' FROM $table") or die(mysql_error());
}
}
}
```